# Storm dynamic topology

Tags: streaming, apache-storm

Does Storm support dynamic topology? The functionality I want from this is to dynamically change the topology according to the user requirement while the Storm topology is running. For example, when user want to know the top-10 words of a stream, I use the top-10 bolt to process it, when user want to know something else, I use the other bolt to process the stream and 'unplug' the top-10 bolt.

I know it could be done by partition the stream or duplicate the stream and alway running every functionalities and only demo the data we want, or we could shut down the stream and update another topology, but is there a 'hot plug-in' way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was added on STORM-561, on 03/Jun/15:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-561

Answer (score 5):

You can't dinamically change a Storm topology's structure, i.e. modify the spouts and bolts wiring. A Storm topology's wiring is always static.

However, you could implement the needed functionality in other ways you already described. IMHO, the best, most logical way would be by running multiple topologies -- in case the data processing differs greatly. But if most of the processing is similar in both cases, just duplicate the source stream and process the data in different branches of the same topology.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to do this (switch out one bolt for another), but what you can do is write a bolt that executes arbitrary code based on the input it receives. So long as your input and output has the same structure in storm (same tuples emitted), you could theoretically execute whatever you wanted at run time in your bolt. This is especially easy if you build your bolt in Clojure, but it's possible in essentially every language you can use with Storm.

However, this probably doesn't make a lot of sense as most computations you'll want to do involve more than one bolt and lend themselves to passing differently structured tuples around. As schiavuzzi already said in their answer, you're probably better off running multiple topologies if there are multiple, independent computations you'd like to do to a stream.

Answer (score 0):

For hot deployment there is a new streaming platform from eBay.
Jetstream:  https://github.com/pulsarIO/jetstream.
It has a built in config management tool and your config sits in mongodb. When user modify the config bean, the tool will publish the notification to zookeeper, the corresponding JetStream applications will be get notified and change the config dynamically