# Dynamic Topologies vs Fine-grained topologies in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

Quick Background: 
A customer can have multiple event processors (Actions to be taken on a particular input) and each of these event processors could be changed independently.  
As an optimization we have grouped all the processors for a single customer into a single Topology. The advantage is isolation across customers and on the flip side entire topology for a customer needs to be redeployed even if a single processor is changed, plus the downtime it takes to kill a topology and redeploy the new topology.

Now the options that I am contemplating is:

1. Dynamic Topology: No easy way to change the spouts and bolts at
   runtime. Even `storm swap` also doesn't seem to be available just yet. Is there a way to dynamically update topologies without deployment or any way to hot deploy topologies.
2. Have one topology per event processor per customer. That would end up having thousands or even 100 thousand topologies and obviously seems incorrect.

Have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353256/storm-dynamic-topology) old post, but not much of help. Whats the recommendation.

Comment: What do you mean by "processor" and " all processors of a single customer into a single topology"? Furthermore, there is no real question. The sentence is cut: "In essence is there a way to..."

Comment: Processors are just event processors - a certain action to be taken for a given input. We have packaged multiple such processors into a single topology, instead of having a topology per processor.